# Ideal Surface finish in turning

Tags: manufacturing-engineering, machining

Why not depth of cut is equal to peak to valley height in ideal turning? I know the expression for peak to valley height in terms of feed. Though it seems correct, independance of peak to valley height on depth of cut contradicts my intution. Can anyone help me ?

[image]

https://www.custompartnet.com/calculator/turning-surface-roughness

Comment: I don't think your description is clear to other people. Please provide a sketch for the application, or provide more clue for the puzzle.

Comment: I posted an image on behalf of the OP. Verify that it is indeed what you are asking. Though the image itself seems to answer the OP's question. The turning tool can cut the workpiece on the edge advancing in the Z-axis which is not the same as nose of the tool where the relief begins ends up leaving marks on the remaining material.

Comment: Difficult to imagine much connection between depth of cut and surface roughness. Tool geometry, cutting speed , material character , lubrication, and other factors affect surface roughness.  I once turned test bars from "free machining brass" ; being young I thought how easy does this cut?  I made a 0,25" deep cut in a one inch round ; The surface was "smooth" and became the test bar surface.

Comment: @DKNguyen Thank you! If i had seen the image, i would not have asked the question. I couldnt find it in google.

Comment: "Ideal" is not a specification.  Are you trying for maximum material removal?  A certain finish?  Tool life?  etc.

Answer (score 1):

Simple definition of depth of cut, I believe, is the nominal difference in radius of the work before vs after the cut.

This would be the roughness *only* when the Z feed rate was equal to
(the "tool width" corresponding to the depth of cut) per each 1 revolution. I.e. the back side of the tool is also cutting in this scenario.

If the feed is slower compared to the RPM, practically all the cut is by the front side of the tool. The roughness is more a function of the tool point and material properties.